# firestore functions returns undefined when I read database with .where()

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

```
function checkUsernameExistence(InputUsername){
    const UsernameRef = db.collection('Users').where("Username", "==", InputUsername);

    UsernameRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot){
        if(querySnapshot.empty){
            //No user has found
            console.log("No User has found");
//          OutputUsername = false;
            return false;
        }else{
            //User has found
            console.log("User has found");
//          OutputUsername = true;
            return true;
        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });

}
```

I'm planning on creating a register page. The code from above is to find an existing Username when post request for register is called. I've manage to read the data from db, and checked it with .empty, and somehow reading a data and console.log works fine. But the return value is always undefined, and returns it before the console.log. How can I get the right return value?

Answer (score 1):

Your `return` statements are inside a callback function (`), not inside the` function. This means that nobody currently ever sees your inner return values.

To make this work, you'll want to bubble up the promise/value and then return it from the function:

```
function checkUsernameExistence(InputUsername){
    const UsernameRef = db.collection('Users').where("Username", "==", InputUsername);

    return UsernameRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot){
        if(querySnapshot.empty){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });

}
```

Then you call this with:

```
checkUsernameExistence("Yisub Heo").then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Note that the result is only valid *inside* the `then()` callback here.

---

Alternatively, you can mark the function as `async` and then `await` its result when calling:

```
async function checkUsernameExistence(InputUsername){
    const UsernameRef = db.collection('Users').where("Username", "==", InputUsername);

    return UsernameRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot){
        if(querySnapshot.empty){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });

}
let result = await checkUsernameExistence("Yisub Heo");
console.log(result);
```